# SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Install

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL EXPRESS 2008 Advanced then I downloaded 64 bits Management Studio. It says install service pack 1 for SQL. I downloaded service pack 1, it says nothing to update :(

So how do I install management studio?

Comment: You've come to the wrong place but it is undeniable that the installer for the 2008 version of this product is historically awful.

Comment: ok should I delete from here then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your OS you may need to look at re-installing SQL Server 2008 Express w Advanced with SP1 slipstreamed into the installation.

Here's a guide on how you can [do it](http://johndelizo.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!5686721B6E7BA618!2310.entry).  How are your robocopy skillz?

Comment: This is a good answer but we really need some more details: What OS are you using? Are you only attempting to install Management Studio?